# Arduino library for ESP8266 - WiFiClientSecure - which SSL certificates are needed?

Tags: ssl, esp8266, lets-encrypt, arduino-esp8266, certbot

`WiFiClientSecure` of Arduino library for ESP8266 has methods: `setCACert`, `setCertificate`, `setPrivateKey`.

I need some explanation what is what and for what purpose.

When I'm creating a certificate for my server with *Let's Encrypt* I get `cert.pem`, `chain.pem`, `fullchain.pem`, `privkey.pem`.

Which files should be used for `WiFiClientSecure`?
Should I generate another private key(s?) for my ESPs which are working as clients?

@Edit

Ok, so what I learnt so far is that the private key is different for every ESP8266. But I still don't know how to handle it. How to generate those private keys? How to handle them from the server's side?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use client verification you need those two:

- setCertificate: this will be your client certificate
- setPrivateKey: this will be the corresponding key

Here is an website I found useful:

https://nofurtherquestions.wordpress.com/2016/03/14/making-an-esp8266-web-accessible/ - Chapter "Code"

Comment: Please add some summary about your link. See [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)